# Python: Maximum Subarray Sum

Tags: python, sum, logic, maximize, sub-array

I've just tried to start learning Python today, so I am not knowledgeable when it comes to it's functions. However, I found the maximum subarray problem, and wanted to try and solve it with the few, simple logical commands I have at my disposal. I have gotten stuck, and am almost certain the problem is in my logic and not syntaxual, though I may very well be wrong. Here is my code so far...

```
def maxSequence(arr): #Latest attempt, some issue.
  old_arr = []
  print(arr)
  while old_arr != arr:
    old_arr = arr
    if arr[0] > 0 and arr[len(arr)-1] > 0: #For when both sides are positive, need to be sure there is not anything to be gained by eliminating some side section
      new_sum = 0
      y=0
      while new_sum >= 0 and y != -1:
        new_sum = sum(arr[:y])
        y=y+1
        if y == len(arr)-1:
          y=-1
      if y != -1:
        arr = arr[y-1:]
      print("left %s" %(new_sum))
      print("left %s" % (arr))
      new_sum = 0
      y = 0
      while new_sum >= 0 and y != -1:
        new_sum=sum(arr[(len(arr)-y):])
        y=y+1
        if y == len(arr)-1:
          y=-1
      if y != -1:
        arr = arr[:len(arr)-y+1]
      print("right %s" %(new_sum))
      print("right %s" % (arr))
    else:
      while arr[0] < 0 or arr[len(arr)-1] < 0: #To eliminate negatives on sides
        if arr[0] < 0:
         arr = arr[1:]
        if arr[len(arr)-1] < 0:
         arr = arr[:len(arr)-1]
        print("negative %s" % (arr))
  print(arr)
  print(sum(arr))
```

The various print functions show each decision made by the program, and help me visualize what is going on as it executes the loops.

It is not giving the correct result of 105 when given the list

```
[26, -25, -23, -2, 3, -6, -5, 15, 7, 8, 17, 15, 29, -2, 16, -25, -8, -25, -27, 15, -29, -11, -12, 1, -14, 21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27, -18, 6, -13, -13, 25, -22, 8, 9, -4, -25, 17, -26]
```

It ends up with a sum of 94, having reduced the list to

```
[21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6]
```

Sorry for the long post, but I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Thank you for your help in advance!

Here is the output when the aforementioned list is given as input, I have gone through and looked at each step, and every elimination from the list seems logical to me, I do not know how one could end up with an ending sum of 105. If anyone could please help me understand, I would really appreciate it!

```
[26, -25, -23, -2, 3, -6, -5, 15, 7, 8, 17, 15, 29, -2, 16, -25, -8, -25, 
-27, 15, -29, -11, -12, 1, -14, 21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, 
-25, 27, -18, 6, -13, -13, 25, -22, 8, 9, -4, -25, 17, -26]
negative [26, -25, -23, -2, 3, -6, -5, 15, 7, 8, 17, 15, 29, -2, 16, -25, 
-8, -25, -27, 15, -29, -11, -12, 1, -14, 21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 
11, 6, -10, -25, 27, -18, 6, -13, -13, 25, -22, 8, 9, -4, -25, 17]
left -22
left [-2, 3, -6, -5, 15, 7, 8, 17, 15, 29, -2, 16, -25, -8, -25, -27, 15, 
-29, -11, -12, 1, -14, 21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27, 
-18, 6, -13, -13, 25, -22, 8, 9, -4, -25, 17]
right -8
right [-2, 3, -6, -5, 15, 7, 8, 17, 15, 29, -2, 16, -25, -8, -25, -27, 15, 
-29, -11, -12, 1, -14, 21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27, 
-18, 6, -13, -13, 25, -22, 8, 9, -4]
negative [3, -6, -5, 15, 7, 8, 17, 15, 29, -2, 16, -25, -8, -25, -27, 15, 
-29, -11, -12, 1, -14, 21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27, 
-18, 6, -13, -13, 25, -22, 8, 9]
left -3
left [-5, 15, 7, 8, 17, 15, 29, -2, 16, -25, -8, -25, -27, 15, -29, -11, 
-12, 1, -14, 21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27, -18, 6, 
-13, -13, 25, -22, 8, 9]
right -5
right [-5, 15, 7, 8, 17, 15, 29, -2, 16, -25, -8, -25, -27, 15, -29, -11, 
-12, 1, -14, 21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27, -18, 6, 
-13, -13, 25]
negative [15, 7, 8, 17, 15, 29, -2, 16, -25, -8, -25, -27, 15, -29, -11, 
-12, 1, -14, 21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27, -18, 6, 
-13, -13, 25]
left -5
left [-12, 1, -14, 21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27, 
-18, 6, -13, -13, 25]
right -1
right [-12, 1, -14, 21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27, 
-18, 6]
negative [1, -14, 21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27, -18, 
6]
left -13
left [21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27, -18, 6]
right -12
right [21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27]
left 84
left [21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6, -10, -25, 27]
right -8
right [21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6]
left 77
left [21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6]
right 53
right [21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6]
[21, 20, 30, -29, 17, 9, -19, 28, 11, 6]
94
```

Comment: Could you give a brief outline of the problem you're trying to solve?  Without looking at your code in depth, it looks like you're trying to get the maximum sublist of the list (that is to say adjacent elements).  Are there any other constraints?  (length, etc.)

Comment: That is correct, there are no constraints other than it needing to be the sublist of the list that has the maximum sum out of all possible sublists.

Comment: Not the cause of your current problem, but you don't seem to be handling zeros in the input correctly.

Comment: Here's a more python-y solution `max((l[start:end] for start in range(len(l)) for end in range(start+1, len(l)+1)), key=sum)`

Comment: This is definitely not the most efficient way to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll demonstrate what's wrong with your algorithm with a little example.

Say the input is

```
[2, -3, 1]
```

`[2]` is clearly the maximum subarray. However, your algorithm will look at this part:

```
[2, -3, 1]
 ^^^^^
```

and see that it can increase the sum of the array by deleting `[2, -3]`.

Deleting negative subarrays from the ends does the wrong thing if the maximum subarray is part of a negative subarray. You'll need a smarter algorithm.

Comment: Thank you! That's definitely it!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use **Kadane’s Algorithm** which takes O(n) time??

**Kadane’s Algorithm(DP):**

```
Initialize:
    max_so_far = 0
    max_ending_here = 0

Loop for each element of the array
  (a) max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i]
  (b) if(max_ending_here < 0)
            max_ending_here = 0
  (c) if(max_so_far < max_ending_here)
            max_so_far = max_ending_here
return max_so_far
```

Comment: I didn't research the problem before trying to figure it out, I was sure it had been solved but just wanted to try and figure it out. I'll be sure to look at this solution though!

Comment: It is the most efficient solution for these type of problems.

Comment: @MarkM: It is a pseudo code, don't you know? I thought with rep over 3500, you must be wise enough to understand it :p

Answer (score 0):

```
def contiguous(list_val, size):
    if size<=len(list_val):
        iterations = len(list_val)-size+1
        count = 0
        num = []
        for i in range(iterations):
            sum_val = 0
            for j in range(count,size):
            sum_val+=list_val[j]
            num.append(sum_val)
            count +=1
            size +=1
        print(max(num))
    else:
        print("Error: given size {} is greater than length of list".format(size))

    list_val = input("Enter list: ")
    size = input("Enter the pos: ")
    contiguous(list_val, size)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code .this works on O(n ) time complexity because it just runs the n times.

```
def manSubArraySum(a):
    currentbest = 0
    overallbest = a[0]
    for p in a: # [1,2,-2,4]
        currentbest = currentbest+p # first step cb = -10
        if currentbest> overallbest: # !true
            overallbest = currentbest
        if currentbest<0: # nottrue
            currentbest =0 # 0

    return overallbest
```